# Facing Browser Compatibility issue with IE-9

Tags: javascript, browser, compatibility, meta-tags, oracle-adf

i am facing compatibility issue with my ADF web application. Tried adding meta tag - '`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />`' and even tried injecting java script to suppress the compatibility issue but nothing is reflecting. Below is the java script-

`

```
<af:resource type="javascript">
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute('http-equiv', 'X-UA-Compatible');
meta.setAttribute('content', 'IE=Edge');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
</af:resource>
```

`

Adding meta tag in .jspx page as below-

1)
'

```
<af:document>
 <f:facet name="metaContainer">
  <f:verbatim>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8;IE=7;IE=EDGE"/>
  </f:verbatim>
 </f:facet>
-----
<f:facet>
----
----
</f:facet>
</af:document>
```

'

2) 
'

```
<af:document>    
   <f:facet name="metaContainer">        
      <af:group id="metaContainer"> 
           <trh:meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7;      IE=EDGE"/>
      </af:group>        
   </f:facet>
</af:document>
```

'

```
None of the above approaches are working with the application, Kindly help me out with your suggestions.

 Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know what kind of compatibility issue you are facing exactly, IE versions, Jdeveloper version etc.

But, as a wild guess, I will suggest this blog:
http://jonasdegraaff.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/how-to-run-your-adf-111x-application.html

Comment: Thank you for the response florinmarcus, i was facing issue with IE versions and resolved by using few patches for Jdeveloper and by adding below context params to xml file.                                      <context-param>
        <param-name>oracle.adf.view.rich.HIDE_UNSUPPORTED_BROWSER_ALERTS</param-name>
        <param-value>IECompatibilityModes</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Agent#OVERRIDE_IE_COMPATIBILITY_MODE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

Answer (score 0):

Above said issue can be resolved by using few patches for Jdeveloper and by adding below context params to xml file.

```
<context-param> 
  <paramname>oracle.adf.view.rich.HIDE_UNSUPPORTED_BROWSER_ALERTS</paramname> 
  <param-value>IECompatibilityModes</param-value>
  </context-param> 

  <context-param>      <paramname>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Agent#OVERRIDE_IE_COMPATIBILITY_MODE<pa‌​ram-name> 
  <param-value>true</param-value> 
  </context-param>
```